# Django Python Timeseries - Reusable app and data base schema

Tags: python, django, time-series

Which Django apps or Python modules are to be recommended for handling and saving into a DB timeseries data. Which database schema is to be recommended for the time series data?

My use case is that I have node models in my db schema having a start and end date, and I want to save for each day between start and end date a value. This can be quite a lot of rows as I have thousands of nodes, and start and end dates are between 1 and 365 days.

My models would look like this, whereas I would be thankful for input regarding a better / performance improved structure:

```
class Node(models.Model):
    """
    Representation of a single node
    """

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    start = models.DateField() 
    end = models.DateField()

class TimeSeries(models.Model)
     """
     holds the time series values. For each day between start and end date one TimeSeries object will be created
     """
     node = models.ForeignKey(Node)
     date = models.DateField() #holds a specific date between start and end date of node
     value = models.IntegerField(max_length=2)
```

Comment: Have you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4330640/realtime-data-processing-in-django-python)? Do any of those solutions sound close to what you need?

Comment: Thanks. But it s not really what I m looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say your best bet is **Pandas**. They take the best of NumPy, scikits etc. and package it.

1. [Pandas' Time Series functionality](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html). Even though the **pyTseries** is no longer active (merged into Pandas) the [documentation is good to browse](http://pytseries.sourceforge.net/genindex.html).
2. If ARMA is of interest, check out these sets of "[statsmodels](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/examples/generated/ex_arma2.html)."

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. Pandas looks really promising. Do you also have experience regarding how to best setup the DB structure for the time series. I m a bit worried regarding performance, since I will have to save and access thousands of rows for the time series.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your DB structure? Give us a sample of some nodes and dates maybe? pandas can handle big numbers, no problem. It comes down to your machine in the end.

Comment: I updated my question. I m generally asking whether the db structure is fine, or whether I should split up the TimeSeries table somehow to not end up with 100000 of rows in one table. I think access performance will be better if one acts on more tables with smaller data sets.

Comment: @Tom Your structure looks reasonable. I'd start with that as-is, and see if you run into problems. 100K rows in one table is usually fine. If performance becomes an issue, you can try to make things a little more efficient, by storing one date and the offsets, rather than storing everything as dates. Also, pandas timeseries has examples that are relevant to what you are doing.

Comment: @ThomasKremmel Did you end up using the Pandas approach, or the schema that you showed in your question? If you used Pandas, what field did you use to store that in the DB?

Comment: I ended up using the DB structure as proposed. But dependent on the use case there are probably better alternatives for storing time series data. ElasticSearch for example